# Entity Framework Scaffold-DbContext Login failed for user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to build an API using Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Core 2 with Entity Framework Core.  I am following the directions from [This Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db).  I am on the section titled: Reverse engineer your model

The command they give to run is as follows:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

My database is an Azure SQL database so I am trying to run this command using the connection string provided from the Azure portal:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=tcp:dbname.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DBNAME_DB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

I am getting returned a

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'username'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection connection, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ModelScaffolder.Generate(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, String projectPath, String outputPath, String rootNamespace, String contextName, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:ba6ca255-04c8-46c2-9d4f-77204728e9f2
Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
Login failed for user 'username'.
```

From this same machine and username and password I am able to login to the database using SSMS.  Does anyone have any suggestions why I am unable to run this command from Visual Studio?

Comment: General tip if you ever get this kind of login error and you're sure the password is correct - first change the username in the string to nonsense like `bigdevjamesXXX`. If you still get `login failed for bigdevjames` it means you're looking in the wrong place in the wrong or old config file. In my case (for the second time now) it was a pesky `$` in the password.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

I figured out my problem.  My password contained the character $ and this needs to be escaped out by using ` before the $.

Comment: In my case ` didn't work, I'm using .Net Core 2.1, so my solution was update the password deleting $ symbols. > ALTER LOGIN yoursqllogin WITH PASSWORD = 'newpassword' OLD_PASSWORD = 'oldpassword'

Comment: @davidrl1000 use a backslash instead of backquote to escape a $.

Comment: Backquote worked for me. Of course! Why not a backquote? (My target database was MS SQL Server on Azure.)

Comment: If the Package Manager Console is using PowerShell you could also use single quotes instead of double so you don't have to escape out characters 
`Scaffold-DbContext 'Server=(localdb)\m ...' `

Comment: This saved me hours of banging my head against the wall, thank you. My password also had a $ in it and I couldn't figure out why I was getting login failed messages when I knew the connection string and login were correct. Thanks!

Comment: Changing " with ' solved my problem. 
Scaffold-DbContext 'Server=tcp:dbname.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DBNAME_DB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

Comment: That's what I get for trying to have a secure password.

Answer (score 21):

Change double quotes " for single quotes '
It is not necessary to add a escape character individually, it works for the rest of the parameters too.

```
Scaffold-DbContext 'Server=tcp:dbname.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DBNAME_DB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Comment: Underrated answer

Comment: Hello @JsonStatham is another way to solve the problem with special characters...

Comment: Seems the behavior changed in year 2021 or 2022 for dotnet6/efcore, I can login until it suddenly doesn't work after a recent upgrade from dotnet5 to dotnet6.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to update your web.config file for connection string. This might be a reason which doesn't allow you to login to azure.

Comment: I do not have a web.config file.  I haven't ever deployed this, and I am still building it.  I'm not sure yet that I will be hosting this behind IIS.  Regardless, I am trying to reverse engineer the database into Entities in my code.  If anything, I would expect the string to be in the appsettings.json file, but I don't have one of those yet either.  Can you show me what you think should be there?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the user login exists on the target SQL Azure database and not only on the Azure SQL Database server.

-- On master database
CREATE LOGIN MaryLogin WITH PASSWORD = '';

-- On the user database

CREATE USER MaryUser FROM LOGIN MaryLogin;

Create a firewall rule on Azure portal to allow access to the Azure SQL Database as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure). Make sure port TCP 1433 is open from your computer.

Answer (score -1):

For me the below command worked when executed in Package Manager console:PM>

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.;Database=Employee;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).