# Scaffold-DbContext "Login Failed" "Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11"

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, localdb

My ASP.NET MVC core application should connect to an existing MSSQL LocalDB file via Entity Framework.

Database-first development requires reverse-engineering the existing database.
Following the instructions in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db), I am running the following command in the NuGet Package Manager Console:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

However I am getting

```
No design-time services were found.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "DatabaseName" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MACHINE-NAME\UserName'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)

Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11
Cannot open database "DatabaseName" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MACHINE-NAME\UserName'.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since "Login failed" might indicate that the database cannot be located, I decided to copy-paste the Connection String in Visual Studio Server Explorer, found by right-clicking the database and picking "Properties".

So the new command was

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\...AbsolutePath...\DatabaseFileName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -verbose
```

and... it worked.
So:

1. Instead of `Server`, I used `Data Source`
2. Instead of using the database name, I wrote the full path to the LocalDb file

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to specify the command as follows:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source={MY-COMPUTER-NAME};Initial Catalog={DATABASE-NAME};Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Replace {MY-COMPUTER-NAME} and {DATABASE-NAME} with values found in Studio's Server Explorer.  I am running SQL Server (not Express) on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

As per other thread, you password may contains special char like $,

Reference : [Entity Framework Scaffold-DbContext Login failed for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399666/entity-framework-scaffold-dbcontext-login-failed-for-user#)