# Difficulties connecting to database through Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core, multi-tier

I am learning ASP.NET core 6 Multitier architecture. I tried making connection to database but I keep getting this error:

```
Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11
Cannot open database "Blogging" requested by the login. 
The login failed.
Login failed for user 'TECHRITOMA\TECHRITOMA Inc'.
```

I tried using the command :

```
 Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

and i was expecting the model class to be created.

Comment: Can you right click the database in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, then select properties. and verify the connectionstring

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48736620/scaffold-dbcontext-login-failed-error-number4060-state1-class11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scaffold-DbContext "Login Failed" "Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48736620/scaffold-dbcontext-login-failed-error-number4060-state1-class11)

Answer (score 0):

As Sydney_dev said. First, Visual studio needs to successfully connect to the local database. Official document: [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16).

.NET Core+EF Scaffold-DbContext command uses.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=ip address;Initial Catalog=database name;User ID=account;password=password;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models;

Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=ip address;Initial Catalog=database name;User ID=account;password=password;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Tables "Blog","Post" -ContextDir Context -Context BlogContext - ContextNamespace New.Namespace
```

[Official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext).